# Filter an ArrayList with Dates by start and end time

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a simple ListView where the data source is an ArrayList with that contains Name, Start and End dates. In iOS I would use a simple NSPredicate to filter the array but here in Android and Java I am confused of what I should use. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

Comment: well i rather use [this](http://quaere.codehaus.org/Getting+started) just make sure you convert the string-dates as time-milliseconds, it has a nice ability to have sql-like-syntax in an array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the Date.before, and Date.after methods.  These allow you to filter a list of dates (for ones in a specific range (for example January)):

a.  Use a Java 8 filter, with a start, and end date.

b.  Use a Java loop / iterator, to check start and end date.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FilterStartAndEndDate {

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    private Collection<Date> dateList = null;
    private Date start = null;
    private Date end = null;

    private FilterStartAndEndDate() throws ParseException {
        dateList = new ArrayList<Date>() {{
            add(sdf.parse("01/01/2016"));
            add(sdf.parse("02/01/2016"));
            add(sdf.parse("03/02/2016"));
            add(sdf.parse("04/01/2016"));
            add(sdf.parse("05/01/2016"));
        }};

        start = sdf.parse("31/12/2015");
        end = sdf.parse("01/02/2016");
    }

    /**
     * Filter dates with Lambda
     *
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    private void getDatesBetweenStartAndFinishWithFilter() throws ParseException {
        dateList.stream()
                .filter(dates -> dates.after(start) && dates.before(end))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .forEach(januaryDate->System.out.println(januaryDate));
    }

    /**
     * Filter dates with Iterator
     *
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    private void getDatesBetweenStartAndFinish() throws ParseException {
        Collection<Date> datesInJanuaryList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Date eachDate : dateList) {
            if (eachDate.after(start) && eachDate.before(end)) {
                datesInJanuaryList.add(eachDate);
            }
        }

        for (Date eachDate : datesInJanuaryList) {
            System.out.println(eachDate);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FilterStartAndEndDate datesInJanuary = new FilterStartAndEndDate();
        datesInJanuary.getDatesBetweenStartAndFinish();
        datesInJanuary.getDatesBetweenStartAndFinishWithFilter();
    }
}
```

The example code filter dates in January, using a Lambda filter, and a Java iterator.  Both use the Date before and after methods.

Comment: Since you can use Java 8 (and even if you could not), do yourself the favour of skipping the long outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes and using [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead.

Comment: The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment, a date with a time-of-day in UTC. As such it is not appropriate for use as a date-only value. Instead use the modern *java.time* classes, specifically `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 2):

## Define a class

> contains Name, Start and End dates

Define a class to hold your event name, start date, and stop date.

### `LocalDate`

Use the modern *java.time* classes for date-time values. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Never use `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, or other terrible old legacy date-time classes.

```
class Event {
    String name;
    LocalDate start, stop;

    // Constructor
    public Event ( String name , LocalDate start , LocalDate stop ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.start = start;
        this.stop = stop;
    }

}
```

Add a method that compares a passed `LocalDate` to the start and stop dates, returning true if contained within our date range. Usually best to compare using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
    public boolean contains ( LocalDate localDate ) {
        // Regarding the beginning date, a short way of saying2 "is equal to or is later than" is "is not before".
        boolean x = ( ! localDate.isBefore( this.start ) ) && localDate.isBefore( this.stop );
        return x;
    }
```

Build a list of these events.

```
List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>();
events.add( new Event( "alpha" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 28 ) ) );
events.add( new Event( "beta" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 28 ) ) );
events.add( new Event( "gamma" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 28 ) ) );
```

Loop these events, checking each if it contains our target date.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 25 );
List< Event > hits = new ArrayList<>( events.size() );
for ( Event event : events ) {
    if ( event.contains( target ) ) {
        hits.add( event );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use Java Streams with lambda syntax, instead of that for-each loop. Same effect; use whichever syntax approach appeals to you.

```
LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 25 );
List< Event > hits = 
    events
    .stream()
    .filter( event -> event.contains( target ) )
    .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

Put all this together into one big class, for the sake of demonstration. I would not nest this `Event` class in real work.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListFilterExample {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        ListFilterExample app = new ListFilterExample();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>();
        events.add( new Event( "alpha" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 28 ) ) );
        events.add( new Event( "beta" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 28 ) ) );
        events.add( new Event( "gamma" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 28 ) ) );

        LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 25 );
        List< Event > hits = new ArrayList<>( events.size() );
        for ( Event event : events ) {
            if ( event.contains( target ) ) {
                hits.add( event );
            }
        }
        System.out.println( hits );
    }

    class Event {
        String name;
        LocalDate start, stop;

        public boolean contains ( LocalDate localDate ) {
            // Regarding the beginning date, a short way of saying2 "is equal to or is later than" is "is not before".
            boolean x = ( ! localDate.isBefore( this.start ) ) && localDate.isBefore( this.stop );
            return x;
        }

        // Constructor
        public Event ( String name , LocalDate start , LocalDate stop ) {
            this.name = name;
            this.start = start;
            this.stop = stop;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString () {
            return "Event{ " +
                   "name='" + name + '\'' +
                   "| start=" + start +
                   "| stop=" + stop +
                   " }";
        }
    }
}
```

When run.

> [Event{ name='beta'| start=2018-02-23| stop=2018-02-28 }]

### `LocalDateRange`

If you want to get fancy, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library (discussed below) to your project. Use its `LocalDateRange` class to represent your stop-start pair of dates explicitly as a date-range. That class already includes a `contains` method, so no need to write you own.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListFilterExample {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        ListFilterExample app = new ListFilterExample();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt () {
        List< Event > events = new ArrayList<>();
        events.add( new Event( "alpha" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 28 ) ) );
        events.add( new Event( "beta" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 28 ) ) );
        events.add( new Event( "gamma" , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MARCH , 28 ) ) );

        LocalDate target = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 25 );
        // Lambda syntax, instead of for-each loop.
        List< Event > hits = events.stream().filter( event -> event.contains( target ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
        System.out.println( hits );
    }

    class Event {
        String name;
        LocalDateRange dateRange;

        public boolean contains ( LocalDate localDate ) {
            // Regarding the beginning date, a short way of saying2 "is equal to or is later than" is "is not before".
            boolean x = this.dateRange.contains( localDate );
            return x;
        }

        // Constructor
        public Event ( String name , LocalDate start , LocalDate stop ) {
            this.name = name;
            this.dateRange = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop );
        }

        @Override
        public String toString () {
            return "Event{ " +
                   "name='" + name + '\'' +
                   "| dateRange=" + dateRange +
                   " }";
        }
    }
}
```

> [Event{ name='beta'| dateRange=2018-02-23/2018-02-28 }]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).